# How to remove white image in splash screen

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic framework development.
I got a headache issue in splash screen for several days.
I customized splash screen with my own image, but I am still getting white background for 3 ~ 4s before my splash screen.
How to remove this white background?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us identify the problem?

Comment: I had same issue, since last 6 month there is nothing solution. kindly share solution if anybody has. And this issue is now rejecting my app from Apple store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround, I've implemented on a few apps

`<preference name=”AutoHideSplashScreen” value=”false”/>
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />`

add this to your `config.xml` file, then call ionic's splashscreen `hide` method on your app's first page.

```
export class FirstPage{
  constructor(
           private platform: Platform,
           public splashScreen: SplashScreen
      ){
      this.platform.ready().then( () => this.splashScreen.hide());


  }
```

By adding `AutoHideSplashScreen` to `false` on `config.xml` makes sure that android app won't try to hide the splash screen after a certain delay. So the splash screen will be visible until you manually hide it on your `FirstPage`

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, but I tried as you mentioned.
But, it is still not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

With this that you are comment I guess that I know which is your "problem".

I think that you build your app with

```
ionic cordova build android
```

for example

This command generate you the project on debug mode, that is faster to build but have some details like size apk or loader screen slower (white screen).

So you need to run

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

It will take more seconds more to build but the apk it will be smaller and improve performance of the app.

Note: When you need to release to store need to run

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Check documentation on ionic page official to more details.

I don't remember but this is also to ios platform.

In my first time with ionic I same affront this issue and was so weird but build with --prod "resolve" the "problem".

I remember that ionic v1 don't have this problem, when post a question mention the version of ionic that you use, now there are 4 versions.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, I am using Ionic v4, and I used your method.
But I can still white screen for several seconds.